# Borel measure of point is 1

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mu: \Sigma \to [0,1]$ a measure. Suppose the existence of a Borel set $E\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ s.t. its measure is $1$ and the measure of every subset of $E$ is either $0$ or $1$. Then there exists a point $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ with measure $1$.

At first I wanted to subdivide $E$ into always smaller and smaller subset to reach single point sets, but since $E$ contains possibly uncountably many points I can't really do that. Then I realized I could maybe show that having such properties forces $E$ to be *itself* a single point set, but I don't see how I could do that.

If anyone can tell me if I'm going in the right direction or if there is a better and/or simpler solution I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @user28431 The answer you deleted can easily be fixed. Start by defining $\nu(S) = \mu(E\cap S)$...

Comment: You can construct a sequence of nested cubes $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3 \subseteq \cdots$ with the properties that the (usual) volume of $I_k$ is $1/2^k$, and $\mu(E \cap I_k) = 1$. Then $\cap_k I_k$ is a singleton $\{x\}$, and we must have $\mu(E \cap \{x\}) = \mu(\cap_k (E \cap I_k)) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\mu(E\cap I_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty}1 = 1$ (the second equality holds because measures are continuous from above). In particular, $E \cap \{x\}$ is nonempty, hence it must equal $\{x\}$, so the above chain of equalities becomes $\mu(\{x\}) = 1$ as desired.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the containments wrong. Should (hopefully obviously) have been $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq \cdots$

Comment: @Bungo Why am I guaranteed to be able to find such an $I_k$? It's not clear to me why $\mu(E\cap I_k)$ would be 1 for every $k$, since such a subset could have measure either 1 or 0.

Comment: Start by partitioning $\mathbb R^n$ into a countable collection of disjoint cubes of (usual) volume 1 (e.g. take the $n$-dimensional products of intervals of the form $[j, j+1)$. Enumerate these cubes as $J_1, J_2, \ldots$. Since measures are countably additive, we have $1 = \mu(E) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(E \cap J_j)$. Each term on the RHS is either $0$ or $1$. Since the sum is $1$, one of the terms on the right hand side, say $\mu(E\cap J_{j_0})$ must be $1$ and the rest must be zero. Let $I_1 = J_{j_0}$. Now partition $I_1$ into $2^n$ disjoint cubes of volume $1/2^n$ and repeat the argument

Comment: By doing this repeatedly, you get a sequence $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \cdots$ such that the volume of $I_k$ is $1/2^{nk}$ (not $1/2^k$ as I wrote earlier) and such that $\mu(E \cap I_k) = 1$. The rest of the argument proceeds as in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there exists none. Let $\mathcal{C}=\{B_{\delta}(x): x\in\mathcal{D},\delta\in{\bf{Q}}^{+}\}$, $\mathcal{D}$ is countable dense in ${\bf{R}}^{n}$. For each $x\in E$, let $B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)$ such that $\delta_{n,x}$ strictly decreasing to zero. Since $\mu(B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)\cap E)\rightarrow\mu\{x\}=0$ and $\mu(B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)\cap E)$ is either $0$ or $1$, then $\mu(B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)\cap E)$ is eventually zero, pick some $n_{x}$ such that $\mu(B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)\cap E)=0$. Now, pick some $c_{x}\in\mathcal{D}$ and $\eta_{n,x}\in{\bf{Q}}^{+}$ such that $x\in B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})\subseteq B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)$. Now $I=\{(\eta_{n,x},c_{x})\}\subseteq{\bf{Q}}^{+}\times\mathcal{D}$ is a countable set and 
\begin{align*}
E&=\bigcup_{x\in E}\{x\}\\
&=\bigcup_{(\eta_{n,x},c_{x})\in I}B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})\cap E,
\end{align*}
so $\mu(E)\leq\displaystyle\sum_{(\eta_{n,x},c_{x})\in I}\mu(B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})\cap E)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: The fact that every subset has measure either $0$ or $1$ holds only for subsets of $E$, why would $\mu(B_{\delta_n})$ be eventually $0$ if it is outside of $E$?

Comment: I think it works right now.

Comment: What if $B_{\delta_n}$ is disjoint from $E$?

Comment: $B_{\delta_{n}}(x)$ contains $x$, I choose $x\in E$ first and then look at the $B_{\delta_{n}}(x)$, for simplicity, just take $\delta_{n}=1/n$.

Comment: Let's call $B_{\frac{1}{N}}$ the cutoff point where the measure becomes 0, then you take $x \in B_{\eta_n} \subset B_{\frac{1}{N}}$ and claim that the union of all these $B_{\eta_n}$ is E. Would this not require every $x \in E$ to be in $B_{\frac{1}{N}}$, which could also not be the case?

Comment: I wrote $B_{1/n}(x)\cap E$, the intersection is needed here. So $\{x\}=\{x\}\cap E=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}(B_{1/n}(x)\cap E)$. And finally $B_{\eta_{n}}(c_{x})\cap E\subseteq B_{1/n}(x)\cap E$. Such $c_{x}$ can be taken as $|x-c_{x}|<1/(3n)$ and then $x\in B_{1/(3n)}(c_{x})\subseteq B_{1/n}(x)$, so here $\eta_{n}=1/(3n)$. I don't see the mistake here so far.

Answer (score 0):

A correct version of a deleted answer: First define a new measure $\nu$ by $\nu(S)=\mu(S\cap E)$. Now every Borel $S\subset\mathbb R^n$ has $\nu(S)$ either $0$ or $1$.

Suppose $\nu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x$. For every $x$ let $B_x=B(x,r(x))$, where $r(x)>0$ is so small that $\nu(B_x)=0$.

If $K$ is compact then $K$ is covered by finitely many $B_x$, so $\nu(K)=0$. Hence $\nu(\mathbb R^n)=0$ (since $\mathbb R^n$ is a countable union of compact sets), contradiction.

Comment: Is the last conclusion due to the fact that $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a countable union of compact sets?

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga That's simplest, yes. Or we could note that when people say "Borel measure" in an informal context like MSE they usually really mean "regular Borel measure"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, would you mind to point out the mistake of my solution? I couldn't really see one.

Comment: @user284331 Well for one I have no idea why you think that $E\subset\bigcup_n B_{\eta_n}(c_x)$; that doesn't follow from anything you said And in fact it makes very little sense to me, because you haven't said what the "$x$" is. Is that one fixed $x$. or is there still a hidden $\bigcup_x$ lurking in the background or what?

Comment: The $x$ I have taken from $x\in E$, first, fix such an $x$, and then find the ball.

Comment: @user284331 That doesn't answer my question about $x$. And in any case, there's simply no reason that $E$ should be a subset of that union. Note for example that if $(r_n)$ is an enumeration of the rationals the intervals $(r_n-1/n^2,r_n+1/n^2)$ do not cover $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @user284331 Ah, I see where you said $x\in B_{\eta_n}(c_x)$. If we're really talking about one fixed $x$ then that shows that _that_ $x$ is in the union in question. You need to show that _every_ $x\in E$ lies in the union. (Also there's no reason I can see that it's possible to choose $\eta_n$ and $c_x$ so that $x\in B_{\eta_n}(c_x)$.)

Comment: Actually those $\delta_{n}$ and $\eta_{n}$ depend on $x$, I should write $\delta_{n,x}$ and $\eta_{n,x}$, so I am not claiming that I can find the radii which are uniformly on $x$. Even though then the set $\{\eta_{n,x}\}$ is a subset of positive rational numbers, which is then countable. Not sure if this fixed the issue you raised.

Comment: @user284331 Make up your mind... If those things depend on $x$ then to get $E$ contained in the union you have to take $\bigcup_x$. An uncountable union of null sets need not be a null set. (The reason saying all the $\eta$ are rational doesn't help is the $c_x$.)

Comment: Okay, I would like to have the last comment, if this still doesn't go through, then I will discard my whole solution: the $c_{x}$ is picked from the countable set $\mathcal{D}$, I forgot to state that $\mathcal{D}$ is a countable dense subset of ${\bf{R}}^{n}$.

Comment: @user284331 You never addressed another question. Ok, the first time I asked it was a stupid question because I left half of the question out. How do you get $c_x$ and $\eta_n$ such that $x\in B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})\subseteq B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)$?

Comment: First, choose a positive rational $\eta_{n,x}$ such that $\eta_{n,x}<6^{-1}\delta_{n,x}$. Now choose $c_{x}\in\mathcal{D}$ such that $|c_{x}-x|<\eta_{n,x}$. So $x\in B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})$. Now claim that $B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})\subseteq B_{\delta_{n,x}}(x)$. For $y\in B_{\eta_{n,x}}(c_{x})$ then $|y-x|\leq|y-c_{x}|+|c_{x}-x|<2\eta_{n,x}<\delta_{n,x}$.

Comment: @user284331 Ok I guess. You had the key idea: If not then for every $x$ there exists $r>0$ with $\mu(B(x,r))=0$. Except of course that's not quite right - then once you fix that the whole thing should really be much simpler...